# Parallel processing using dask, numba and xarray

Tags: python, dask, python-xarray

I data stored in an xarray dataarray with dimension `(nt, nb, nx, ny)`
I wrote some code that calculates some quantities cell wise (e.g., for each cell in `nx` and `ny`) between two different values of the 0-th dimension. My processing can be done independently in `nt`, but also in `nx` and `ny`. I don't know how to get this to run in parallel using dask.

The following example demonstrates what I want to do (my calculations are more complex than those used here). However, this runs sequentially, and I'd like to parallelise it, and make use of the chunk structure in the data.

```py
import numpy as np
import xarray as xr
import xarray.tutorial
from numba import njit, float64, float32
from itertools import product

@njit('Tuple((float32[:, :],float32[:,:]))(float32[:, :, :], float32[:, :,:])')
def do_smthg(ar1, ar2):
    n1, n2, n3 = ar1.shape
    outa = np.zeros((n2, n3), dtype=np.float32)
    outb = np.zeros((n2, n3), dtype=np.float32)
    for i in range(n1):
        for j in range(n2):
            outa[i,j] = np.sum(ar1[:, i,j] - ar2[:, i,j])
            outb[i,j] = np.sum(ar1[:, i,j] + ar2[:, i,j])
    return outa, outb
    
da = xarray.tutorial.load_dataset("era5-2mt-2019-03-uk.grib")
da = da.chunk("auto")
F = {}
for (t1,tt1), (t2, tt2) in product(da.t2m.groupby("time.day"),
                           da.t2m.groupby("time.day")):
    # t1 and t2 are timesteps. Calculate for pairs t1 and all times after.
    if t2 > t1:
        F[(t1, t2)] = do_smthg(tt1.values, tt2.values)
```

One way to parallelise this would be to have a dask client available, and map things over, but this requires a lot of thinking and data shifting:

```py
from distributed import LocalCluster, Client
cluster = LocalCluster()
client = Client(cluster)
F = {}
for (t1,tt1), (t2, tt2) in product(da.t2m.groupby("time.day"),
                           da.t2m.groupby("time.day")):
    if t2 > t1:
        F[(t1, t2)] = client.submit(do_smthg, tt1.values, tt2.values)
F = {k:v.result() for k,v in F.items()}
```

This kind of works, but I am unsure there's any cleverl parallelisation going on. Besides, it needs to shift loads of data around. It looks like the kind of thing that some xarray/dask jiggery pokery should make very efficient. I would want to run this on a large dask cluster, where my datasets would be very large (but chunked).

Using `map_blocks` isn't also clear:

```py
# template output dataset
out = xr.Dataset(
    data_vars={"outa":(["lat", "lon"], np.random.rand(33, 49)),
               "outb":(["lat", "lon"], np.random.rand(33, 49))})
out.coords["lat"] = da.coords["latitude"].values
out.coords["lon"] = da.coords["longitude"].values
out = out.chunk("auto")

F = {}
for (t1,tt1), (t2, tt2) in product(da.t2m.groupby("time.day"),
                           da.t2m.groupby("time.day")):
    # t1 and t2 are timesteps. Calculate for pairs t1 and all times after.
    if t2 > t1:
        F[(t1, t2)] = tt1.drop("time").map_blocks(do_smthg, args=[tt2.drop("time")], template=out)
F[(1,5)].outb.values
```

This results in an error when running the numba code

```
TypeError: No matching definition for argument type(s) pyobject, pyobject
```

If I remove the numba wrapper, and just use the vanilla slow Python function, this runs until the end and returns this message

```
~/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dask/core.py in _execute_task(arg, cache, dsk)
    117         # temporaries by their reference count and can execute certain
    118         # operations in-place.
--> 119         return func(*(_execute_task(a, cache) for a in args))
    120     elif not ishashable(arg):
    121         return arg

~/mambaforge/lib/python3.9/site-packages/xarray/core/parallel.py in _wrapper(func, args, kwargs, arg_is_array, expected)
    286 
    287         # check all dims are present
--> 288         missing_dimensions = set(expected["shapes"]) - set(result.sizes)
    289         if missing_dimensions:
    290             raise ValueError(

AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sizes'
```

So there's something strange going on here with passing different variables.

Comment: you're calling `F[(t1, t2)] = tt1.map_blocks(tt2, template=out)`. but the first argument to [`map_blocks`](https://docs.xarray.dev/en/stable/generated/xarray.DataArray.map_blocks.html) must be a *callable* - this is the function which is mapped across all blocks. the error being raised, `'DataArray' object is not callable`, reflects the fact that you're passing a dataarray object in instead if a function.

Comment: Thanks, I updated the example, it was a typo

Answer (score 1):

I believe you need to make the output of `do_smthg` match the template.

I experienced the same `AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'sizes'` using xr.map_blocks when the output of the function was a numpy array.  When I converted the output to be in the expected xarray template, the map_blocks code executed as expected.

Comment: Thanks. Just to clarify. are you suggesting that `do_smthg` should just return an xarray dataset, and not numpy arrays?

Comment: yes, but not just any xarray dataset/dataarray, it has to be one that matches the template given to map_blocks (all the same attributes) or I get errors.

Comment: I'll add that I'm new to map_blocks and came across this question when I got the same error and fiddled around to try to solve it when I couldn't find an answer. I'm not sure this suggestion will work for you but thought I'd post it in case it helps you or others.